# Trying to populate a hibernate bean complex type property from web form

Tags: hibernate, struts2, mapping

I have mapped my objects using `hibernate` and annotations. I can query and create them individually. But when I need to populate one from a form that is a composite type, ie it includes a foreign key of another entity, I don't know how to populate the object property it represents. So something like this:

```
<s:textfield name="page.book" label="book"/>
```

should translate to property `Book` of bean `Page` which in turn translates to foreign key book_id in table pages. I'm not sure how to map my form bean fields to composite types such as `Book`. I keep getting `NullPointerException`'s serverside.

Can someone outline how you'd populate a bean property that's not a simple type?

Comment: Is `Book` an object or a primitive/String property? maybe you need to use `page.book.book_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a input for each property of your `Book` object in bean `Page`.

```
public class Book {
    private int bookId;
    private String bookTitle;
    // and so on...

    // getters and setters *important*
}

public class Page {
    private Book book;
    // and so on...    

    // getters and setters *important*
}
```

You would need both:

```
<s:textfield name="page.book.bookId" label="bookId"/>
```

and:

```
<s:textfield name="page.book.bookTitle" label="bookTitle"/>
```

and any other properties `Book` may have.